# Get leaflet marker from a layer

Tags: leaflet, markers

I'm new to leaflet and am trying to implement a set of markers with different CSS-styles.

So, I am aware that after adding a marker to a map I can access different CSS-attributes by calling getElement() on my marker for example:

```
    marker.addTo(map);
    marker.getElement().style.borderColor = '#000';
```

This works just fine, but when adding a marker to a layer, this can no longer be used since a TypeError occurs (getElement() is undefined). Here is the example code where the error occurs:

```
    myLayer.addLayer(marker);
    marker.getElement().style.borderColor = '#000';
```

Am I overlooking a simpler way to set CSS-Attributes for markers and divicons that are added to layers or is there a similar way to access layer-added markers and divicons in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution that is working for me.
The idea is to extend the function that is used to create the icon.
Last answer here [github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5231](http://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5231) helped a lot.

```
    var borderSize = ...;
    L.DivIcon.Custom = L.DivIcon.extend({
        createIcon: function(oldIcon) {
               var icon = L.DivIcon.prototype.createIcon.call(this, oldIcon);
               icon.style.borderSize = borderSize;
               ...
               return icon;
        }
    })
    var icon = new L.DivIcon.Custom({
        ...
    });        
    var ll = L.latLng(entry.Longitude, entry.Latitude);
    var marker = L.marker(ll, {
      icon: icon
    })
    this.myLayer.addLayer(marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

When not added onto a map (since your parent `myLayer` may not be added to the map itself), a marker does not have any element.

If you do not need to change too many styles individually and dynamically, you might rather use the [`className`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#icon-classname) option of your Icon / DivIcon.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for you answer and the warm welcome! I am already using the `className` option for static CSS-Attributes.
If I understand you correctly I would assign a unique className to a marker and then get the marker with `getElementsByClassName()`?
I tried it with `className: 'icon ' + name + entry.id,`and then to get the icon via `var my_icon = document.getElementsByClassName(name + entry.id)[0];
        my_icon.style.borderWidth = Math.trunc(borderSize) + 'px';`
But this doesn't seem to work either since strangely no element is found.

Comment: Let me say it differently: if the marker is not on the map, it is not in the DOM, hence `document.getElementsByClassName` and the like will not find it. Instead, access the marker, its icon, and change its className. You could try to change individual styles but that would be much more complicated.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense that I can't access it. However I would need to set at least the borderSize for each divicon individually so that would be the second case you mentioned right?
I could probably achieve this by extending the divicon constructor as mentioned here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5231 (last comment). But I am not really sure whether this would work in my case since I would need to pass additional data to the constructor.

Comment: Then go and try for yourself, it is the best way to find a solution instead of talking about it indefinitely. But I am still convinced that a set of predefined classes with each of your desired CSS rules would be good enough already.